# javafx - Alert and stage focus

Tags: java, javafx, focus, javafx-8, alert

For my application I need to know whenever the app's window is being focused or not. For this, I can use `primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener(..)`, which will warn me of changes in focus of the stage.

But I have realized that opening an `Alert` with this `primaryStage` as owner and with modality set to `WINDOW_MODAL` makes the `primaryStage` loose focus (even though the window is in reality focused, or at least in Windows).

Now the problem that I have is that I want to know when the `Window` is focused and not just the `primaryStage`; or at least know if the `Alert` is being focused, but I could not find how.

I have tried to use similare properties on the alert(like `onShowing` and `onHiding`) without success.

Here is a piece of code to illustrate my problem :

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

        primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("primaryStage focused : "+newValue);
        });
        primaryStage.show();

        //create a basic alert
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,"This is a test");
        alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); //will block input to its owner window
        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
        alert.onShowingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("alert onShowing : "+newValue);
        });
        alert.onShownProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("alert onShown : "+newValue);
        });
        alert.onHidingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("alert onHiding : "+newValue);
        });
        alert.onHiddenProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("alert onHidden : "+newValue);
        });
        alert.showAndWait();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Basically it will print this :

```
primaryStage focused : true //stage is created and displayed
primaryStage focused : false //alert is displayed, stage loses focus. alt+tab changes nothing
primaryStage focused : true //alert closed by pressing 'ok'
```

Which is strange because of all other prints that it should produce.
Also ideally I would need a :

```
primaryStage focused : true //stage is created and displayed
primaryStage focused : false //alert is displayed, stage loses focus
alert focused : true //alert gains focus
alert focused : false //alt+tab to an other window
alert focused : true //alt+tab back to this window
alert focused : false //alert closed by pressing 'ok'
primaryStage focused : true //stage regains focus
```

Or something similar. Does anyone has an idea to achieve this, or is this `primaryStage` losing focus to a `WINDOW_MODAL` `Alert` an issue that I should report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I could find a workaround. It is possible for each `buttonType` used in an alert to determine whether it is focused or not. This property changes also when alt+tabbing, thus we can monitor every `buttonType` used and see if only one is focused or not.

Here my solution, a little bit hacky but achieving what I wanted :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

        primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("PrimaryStage focused : "+newValue);
        });
        primaryStage.show();

        //create a basic alert
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"This is a test");
        alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); //will block input to its owner window
        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);

        alert.getButtonTypes().forEach(buttonType -> {
            //add a focus listnener for each buttonType of this alert
            alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonType).focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println(buttonType.getText()+" focused : "+newValue);
                System.out.println("Alert focused : "+isAlertFocused(alert));

            });
        });
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    /** Looks all {@link ButtonType} used in the given {@link Alert} and checks if any of them is
     * focused, hence if the {@link Alert} is being focused
     *
     * @param alert the {@link Alert} we want to check the focused status from
     * @return true if the alert is focused, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isAlertFocused(Alert alert){
        if(alert == null){
            return false;
        }

        final boolean[] focused = {false};
        alert.getButtonTypes().forEach(buttonType -> {
            focused[0] = focused[0] || alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonType).isFocused();
        });
        return focused[0];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I think I can also extend this method to dialog by adding a check of `alert.getDialogPane().isFocused()` inside the `isAlertFocused(Alert alert)` method, but this is out of the scope of my question.